# Unity - character model not blinking

Tags: unity, animation, models

I'm a bit confused as to what's going on, but I've just noticed that my imported character model never blinks during his animations. I currently have 3 animations - an idle, walk and jump. Every aspect of the animations work correctly, but for some reason the blinking doesn't. o_o Looking at the keyframes in the Animation tab, they're there, but they don't work. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Where the animations made from within Unity or from another program and then imported?

Comment: They were made in Blender and then imported. Things like the eye blinks were done using Shape Keys. Does Unity not read/like those, I wonder...?

Comment: Did you [search for existing documentation/guides/Q&A about using Blender Shape Key animations in Unity](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+shape+key)? What did you find, and how have you tried applying this to your use case?

Comment: A couple, but I'm still a bit confused. Would I need to animate anything with shape keys separately via the Shape Key Editor in Blender? Import BlendShapes for my models is always ticked by default, so that's not a problem. Adding a SkinnedMeshRenderer component doesn't show any BlendShapes section either.

Comment: Okay, I've found the BlendShapes section if I click on the character's Body in the Hierarchy, and I can turn two sliders up and down, though they both do the same thing. Not sure why I'd need two of them. But what now? What's the best way to get these working in my animations? Am I supposed to add them manually via the Animator, add a script or what...?